# Navigation Component with ContextMenu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-architecture-navigation, android-contextmenu

I've a MainActivity linked with navigation component. Every fragment has its own implementation of Toolbar and I setup it, calling this method defined in the activity, from the specific fragment:

```
fun setupToolbar(toolbar: Toolbar) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }
```

Now, this is working great, except that now I need to add a context menu (beside the classic options menu) to delete an item of a list. When I long-press a view, this is the result:

[image: Toolbar duplicated]

How can I avoid this duplicate? Why the context menu is not honoring the toolbar I setup earlier?

Comment: Are you using  Contextual Action Bar aka ActionMode for deleting the files?